# How to protect purely html page from unauthorized access?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have admin page which is **purely in html**, After Login as admin It redirect to admin page. Url of admin page is  http://URL/index.html. But this page is also accessible if we just type URL. So any body can access this page if he know the url of this page. So I want to protect this html page from unauthorized access. Here php file, html file are separate. To access that page there will be login id and password. After only matching login id and password, the required page should be load.

```
<head>
    <title>Service for home - Next Generation of Service Provider - Admin               
</head>

<body>
      Welcome admin..
</body>
```

Comment: you can load the php session page using jquery if it is success then show body else hide to body

Comment: Yes priya786 is right. it's good solution.

Comment: If you are loading these templates through php then just move the templates out of the public dir.

Comment: @priya786, thanks for reply but I don't want use php in html code,  So It is possible do that..

Comment: in this you can only use jquery not php

Comment: @ priya786, could you tell me how I will do in javascript, Any tutorial for this..Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do it with client side JavaScript. The user controls their browser. You cannot ask their browser to secure your website from them. Hiding the body if you can't get session data over Ajax is a nonsense idea because they can still use a DOM inspector to look at the hidden body.

Comment: You absolutely must do something server side for any kind of security. If your server supports PHP then you can use that for it. If you want to separate your PHP and HTML then that is fine, just keep the HTML outside the web root and have the PHP read the files and deliver them to the browser.

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks for reply, I am agree with you. Later On I have to develop into PhoneGap application. In phone Gap application which is purely HTML5 and JQuery Mobile and JQuery. Suppose there is customer profile for every customer, So How I will protect the customer profile.

Comment: With something server side (assuming you are connecting to a remote web service). There are plenty of introductory AuthN/AuthZ guides out there.

Comment: @Quentin,  could tell me good one,

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it with .htaccess. And for protection from search engines you can use robot.txt

Answer (score -1):

try`http basic auth` with nginx

```
    location /index.html {
            auth_basic "auth";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

[related tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10)